# Driver that accesses a relative path?

Tags: python, drivers, linked-data

I want to drive a value in a shader node with a Custom Property defined on the World, and have it work when linking the Material into a new file. The first part of that is simple to create:
[image]

This is accessing the World in the file the material was made in. But if I now Link this into a new file, I want it to access world_prop for the World in that file. But it will continue to access it for the World in the original file. Is there a way to achieve this?

I am aware of the Use Self option when using a scripted expression. This allows you to access data from the python object the driver is on. In this case, that is a value node though. So even though that is technically relative, it doesn't let me get the World of the current scene/file.

Is there another option? Like if instead the driver was triggering a script that gets info from the current scene?